# React Native - iOS app crashes on fetching database from firebase - rnfirebase.io

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-ios

In the firebase database, I have only one object. And it has only one value.

In android, everything is working fine. In iOS, the app crashes on 'on' method.

Below message appears in the red screen in iOS:

> undefined is not a function (this._database.native.on...)

Here is the code that I am using in componentDidMount.

```
componentDidMount() {
        database()
            .ref('/checkPlatform')
            .on('value', snapshot => {
                let firebaseData = snapshot.val()
                this.setState({ isAndroidDisable: firebaseData.isPlatformEnabled })
            });
 }
```

Instead of the `on` method, I've also tried `once()`. But no luck.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting "this._database.native.on is not a function" on ios try -

1. run the pod install - after adding firebase new service(database/auth ...)
2. terminate the metro bundler and restart it using "npx react-native start"
3. run "npx react-native run-ios"

This will create a new build and the error should be gone.

Ref: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3379